# Why was this question deleted as "spam or offensive"?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, spam

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41475276.  The question as originally posted [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41475276/1).

It's off-topic, and should have been closed (and perhaps deleted) for that reason, but it isn't spam or offensive.  It looks to me as if some automated system flagged it because it attracted a spam answer and no good answers?

My only concern about this is that it presumably means the author wasn't directed to the appropriate site (Super User) and may have been otherwise penalized.  Is this supposed to have happened?

[image: This question was marked as spam]

[image: original question]

Comment: It got a *very* spammy answer.  Users are getting pretty edgy about this kind of spam where it looks like the question was posted with the *intention* to post spam in an answer.  Not the case here, albeit that it is hard to tell, the user accounts were not created at the same time.  Well, it will not be missed.

Comment: It didn't get to -6 so I expect a moderator casted the binding spam flag.

Comment: Even if it wasn't spam, it certainly didn't belong to Stack Overflow. SuperUser, maaaaybe.

Comment: It's not in MetaSmoke and took almost 4 hours to delete (at 4 in the morning, UTC).  Maybe a bleary-eyed moderator just made a mistake?

Comment: I was that bleary-eyed moderator.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I'm the mod who cast the binding spam flag. I don't remember *exactly* why I flagged it as spam, but it was probably in error.

I think the chain of events went something like this:

The post had a pretty spammy answer [already described by Magisch](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341027/229044) which I flagged. In digging around in the post history of that answer's author, I found a [*very* spammy question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41476187/we-need-some-pages-where-we-could-earn-some-extra-cash) as well.

I think I may have closed that tab or a series of tabs, and returned to this question, got the author of the spammy answer confused with the author of the less spammy (but still off-topic) question, and flagged it. Or, I may have made a bad judgement call and assumed the author of the question was generating spam questions for the second person to post spam answers to.

Either way, it was a bad job on my behalf. I've cleared the spam flag, undeleted the question, and closed it as off-topic.

Answer (score 13):

This looks oh so very much like a spam seed question. You see, spammers have long since adapted the tactic to create separate accounts to ask questions that look just tailored to receive their sales pitch as an answer. People get *very* wary of questions that look like that, and this question *reeks* of that.

It looks like this question was deleted at -3, which means a moderator cast the ultimately binding spam flag.

Moderators also have access to information we're not privy to, so it may be entirely possible that this was the case and the question author and spammer were the same person, using 2 different accounts.

If you take a look at the answer this question got, it feels like the company pre-wrote both of these and just posted them from different accounts, or encouraged a customer to post this to then make their sales pitch on SO and get free advertisement.

The (also spam deleted) answer the Q got for reference:

[image]

*(Credit to @ivarni for the image)*

Ultimately, only the moderator who deleted it can clarify what truly happened, but this is *very* suspicious from the outset already, and moderators can look for a whole lot more suspicious data then we can.

Comment: If it's really the guys from Rufus that's pretty cool because it's a free tool, with source even available. 

"I'm not a spam bot" - what I wanted to type but i'm automatically one because I now vouch for a seemingly obvious spammer...

Anyway, I hope Harry Johnston figures out his installation - I got stuck at a Windows 10 logo for 3 weeks till I figured out I had to install windows on a usb from linux so that I can boot into windows, mod my bios with a custom cpu signature because Windows does not allow 'unofficial' cpu-mobo combos, rip.

Comment: @AjOtto whatever the circumstances, _"Use our tool at [link] and email us at [mail] if you can't figure it out"_ is simply not how this site works, besides the question and answer being horribly off-topic.

Comment: Good point, thank you for keeping it topical & factual, as this site should be, I've re-read it all with more focus and I see what you mean now.

Comment: ["separate", it is, not "seperate"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/seperate). And ["receive" instead of "recieve"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/seperate).